# Nema 17 and 23 motor with TB6600 Raspberry pi 4 4GB control

Tags: gpio, raspberry-pi4

My motors (both nema 17 and 23) do not seem to run. I use TB6600 driver for them and the DIP switches are set to 16 microstep and 2A (nema 17) and 3A (nema 23). Is there any problem with my code or any add ons?

Or maybe the A and B wirings are mixed up, I tested the pairs based on their resistance to match what pairs together. I directly connected my drivers to the GPIO pins on my RPi 4 and from the drivers to the stepper motors. I am not using those HATs for these I cant seem to find any available here on my area.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# Define GPIO pins for Step, Direction, and Enable
STEP_PIN = 17
DIR_PIN = 18
ENABLE_PIN = 27

# Set GPIO mode and pins
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(STEP_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(DIR_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(ENABLE_PIN, GPIO.OUT)

# Function to control motor movement
def move_motor(steps, delay):
    # Set direction (True for clockwise, False for counterclockwise)
    GPIO.output(DIR_PIN, True)  # Change to False if you want to move counterclockwise

    # Enable the motor driver
    GPIO.output(ENABLE_PIN, True)

    # Generate step pulses to move the motor
    for _ in range(steps):
        GPIO.output(STEP_PIN, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(delay)
        GPIO.output(STEP_PIN, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(delay)

    # Disable the motor driver
    GPIO.output(ENABLE_PIN, False)

# Example usage: Move the motor 200 steps with a delay of 0.005 seconds between steps
move_motor(200, 0.005)

# Cleanup GPIO pins
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Tried to drive them using the code below but when I try the nema 23, it only moved for a bit then the python script finishes. I just want to test if they work or not because I will use them for our DIY machine that moves in different axes.